# Inequality $\Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{\frac{1}{27}}\leq ab^{abc}+bc^{abc}+ca^{abc}\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lagrange-multiplier

It's a problem from my own :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ then we have :
>   $$\Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{\frac{1}{27}}\leq a\Big(b^{abc}\Big)+b\Big(c^{abc}\Big)+c\Big(a^{abc}\Big)=f(a,b,c)\leq 1$$

The idea was to create an inequality where $f(a,b,c)$ takes his values in a very little interval because we have $\Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{\frac{1}{27}}-1<-0.0398$

Furthermore I create this where all the classical method fails .I think to Am-Gm , Jensen , Tchebytchev and so on ...

My first idea was to use rearrangement inequality but it doesn't works too .

Thirdly my idea was to use the Lagrange multiplier but I'm skeptical about this method .

An other point of view is to put $abc=\alpha=constant$ and study the behavior of $f(a,b,c)$.

That's all for me if you have a hint it would be great .

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Edit

As pointed out by WE tutorial school The RHS is obvious but what happend for the LHS ?

Comment: Do you mean $(ab)^{abc}+\ldots$?  The RHS is easy if you only mean to say $ab^{abc}+\ldots$.  This is because $b<1$, and so $b^{abc}<1$.  Hence $ab^{abc}<a$.  And with two more similar inequalities we get $ab^{abc}+\ldots<1$.

Comment: Hmmmm but judging from the LHS, you probably mean $ab^{abc}+\ldots$, rather than what I just suggested.  So, yes, you can replace $abc$ in the exponent by any positive parameter $\alpha$, and you will still get $ab^\alpha+bc^\alpha+ca^\alpha<a+b+c=1$.